# AttributeError on 'tkinter' project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I get the following AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\thaku\OneDrive\Desktop\tkinter python\tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
        import tkinter
      File "C:\Users\thaku\OneDrive\Desktop\tkinter python\tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
        win = tkinter.Tk()
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

this is my code snippet

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()
win.title('GUI')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try renaming your file from `tkinter.py` to something else.

Comment: When I tried to run the code from a file named `tkinter.py` using IDLE, it just crashes which is an interesting bug in IDLE.

Comment: @TheLizzard wow that such thing is possible in Python. The python interpreter should be smart enough to not import the file itself from the same file. Should file a bug, i think.

Comment: @Programmer the bug isn't in python. Python first looks at files with that name in the dir of the base program. The strange thing is that naming a file `tkinter.py` and running it confuses IDLE and it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

From the traceback I can see that you named your file `tkinter.py` which confuses python  as it thinks that you are trying to import that file from itself. If you rename your file to something else it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have named you file `tkinter.py` because of which python imports that file as the module and also runs the same file while running which creates a loop and gives that error

Solution:
Name your file something else.
For example:- `tkinter_.py` or whatever else you want except for the modules name itself as that is reserved for the python interpreter.

Comment: It's my Pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Well I looked into Traceback and found the problem.

You have named the file on which you have been working on as `tkinter.py`. While using the command `import tkinter` it imports your file *(the one you are working on)* itself **rather than import the module `tkinter`**.

The preferred answer would be that you rename the file you are working on as `tkinter_pratice.py` or something like that.

> You can now learn that you can't give a file the same name as a module's name as if would import itself rather than importing that particular module.